# Mutation Observer with External Callback Function Code

Tags: javascript, callback, mutation-observers

I am trying to rewrite the following Mutation Observer code:

```
var target = document.querySelector('div#cart');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log(mutation.type);
    });
});

var config = { childList: true, attributes: true, characterData: true, subtree: true };
observer.observe(target, config);
```

Into the script below:

```
var target = document.querySelector('div#cart'), observer, moCallback, config;

moCallback = function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach( mutation ) {
        console.log(mutation.type);
    }
};

var array = moCallback;

observer = new MutationObserver( array );

config = { childList: true, attributes: true, characterData: true, subtree: true };
observer.observe(target, config);
```

The second script is easier for me to read since it doesn't have the embedded callback function; however, I can't get it to work.

How can I rewrite my Mutation Observer with an external callback function instead of an inline anonymous function?

Comment: Your forEach is messed up in your second script, change it such that it matches the one in script1.

Comment: I updated the forEach() loop but the syntax is still messed up. Can Mutation Observer be called with an external callback? If yes, I have not found an example online that I can follow.

Comment: Callback functions do not need to be defined inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
/*
if you run this script on this page, you will see that it works as expected.
*/
var target = document.getElementById('header'); // This is the area you're watching for changes. If it's not working, increase the scope (go up the selector cascade to parent elements).
var observer = new MutationObserver(mutate);

function mutate(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) { // When the main image changes...
        console.log(mutation.type);
    });
}

var config = { childList: true, attributes: true, characterData: true, subtree: true };
observer.observe(target, config);
setTimeout(function(){
  target.className = "some class";
},2000);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much, nick!

Comment: Awesome.  No problem